# We should not return duplicate questions as unanswered

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I just searched

```
[apache-flink]answers:0
```

and ordered it by most votes.

This question comes out on top:
[Beam pipeline does not produce any output after GroupByKey with windowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718318/beam-pipeline-does-not-produce-any-output-after-groupbykey-with-windowing)

I don't believe this is sensible, the question has answers they just happen to live somewhere else.

> This question already has answers here: Watermark getting stuck (2
> answers)

I am not sure how difficult this is from a technical perspective, but if an 'unanswered' question has been linked as a duplicate, I think we should count the answers in the linked post instead. (Or simpler, at least count the linked thread as an answer to avoid it popping up as unanswered).

Comment: Duplicates can be very useful! It's all in the wording of the question (and your search query) -- two different sounding questions may have the same answer, so ultimately it only depends on which one pops up first. But that dup is just a single click away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't pop up in the [unanswered tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-flink?tab=Unanswered) of the tag results, so this is already working.  Note that this uses a slightly different definition of "answered" than your search: it's not considered answered until one of the answers is upvoted or accepted.

For searching for questions with no answers whatsoever, you can just [add `closed:no` to your query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bapache-flink%5D%20answers%3A0%20closed%3Ano) to filter out duplicates and other closed questions, or [add `duplicate:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapache-flink%5D%20answers%3A0%20duplicate%3Ano) to remove only duplicates.

This is useful, as it allows you to be more specific about what you want to search for: you may actually want to find duplicates with no answers on the question itself.